# Is the following async enabled code liable to cause a deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

```
    public async Task<Foo> Execute(int id)
    {
        var parameters = new { id};

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
        {
            await con.OpenAsync();

            return await con.QueryAsync<foo>(
                "dbo.uspGetMeFoo",
                parameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                commandTimeout: int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlCommandTimeout"]))
                .ContinueWith(task =>  task.Result.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
```

This method is awaited on in a calling class, where - some time after - I would like to use the result without explicitly blocking.

I can remedy this to not use the `ContinueWith` above, by returning `Task<IEnumerable<Foo>>` and `FirstOrDefault()` this in the calling code instead.

From what I have read the blocking above is smelly and worse will cause problems, potentially a deadlock.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Servy says, you could just as easily write

```
public async Task<Foo> Execute(Foo foo )
{
    var parameters = new { id = id};

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
    {
        var timeout = int.Parse(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlCommandTimeout"]);

        await con.OpenAsync();

        var query = await con.QueryAsync<Foo>(
            "dbo.uspGetMeFoo",
            parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            commandTimeout: timeout);

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This is not going to cause a deadlock unless `dbo.uspGetMeFoo` does something unexpected and dumb. That would not be an issue with the code in the question.

Comment: I was looking for a way to rewrite it and this is abundantly sensible.  In firming up my ideas I am getting confused at the relevant and timely place to call task.Result.  My first thoughts were that I was mixing async and sync code.

Comment: So actually I would have just been mixing up 2 ways to do the same thing. The continuation is a little bit more  implicit in this manner which, I believe, would be more in keeping with what is used elsewhere and would be more consistent with the rest of the code in place.

Comment: Just so we are on the same hymn sheet,  I might not have been clear,  I meant that what you suggested (as opposed to the code I had put in question) seems to make more sense and is nicer and more consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `Result` on an already completed `Task` (you *know* that the task will be completed if its continuation is firing) is not going to cause a deadlock.

A deadlock is caused when the task needs to be able to schedule an operation on another thread/context in order to be able to complete, but where that thread/context is blocking on the result.  Since the task is already completed, blocking a thread/context cannot possibly prevent it from being completed.

That said, you could just as easily `await` the task instead of calling `ContinueWith`.